# Copy a large (over 4k) selection of text from the screen scrollback buffer into the system clipboard

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen, clipboard

I wan't to be able to copy-paste the contents of my `screen` scrollback buffer into various browser text fields, usually when pasting an excerpt from a log file. One way that works well is the following:

```
$ xsel -bi
<CTRL-A ]> Enter
<CTRL-d>
```

Then simply pasting into the browser with `CTRL-v`. This works well for short excerpts of text. The problem is that these log excerpts often exceed 4 kilobytes, perhaps reaching 16k or 32k at a maximum. This causes `CTRL-v` to hang in the browser, perhaps due to the issues raised in the following two questions:

- http://unix.funmontage.com/questions/204815/terminal-does-not-accept-pasted-or-typed-lines-of-more-than-1024-characters#
- http://unix.funmontage.com/questions/131105/how-to-read-over-4k-input-without-new-lines-on-a-terminal

I tried the solutions suggested in the answers to these questions to no avail. Is there any other way of getting around the 4k buffer limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using a temporary file, you could do:

```
C-a : writebuf filename
$ xsel -bi < filename
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea. It creates the file correctly, but pasting into the browser still hangs for around a 10k block of text that was selected using this approach. Incidentally, pasting into a file in the terminal using `CTRL-Shift-v` works (this works with the original approach I tried above as well). BTW, manually copying from the file via `CTRL-c` using TextEditor works, but isn't satisfactory as a complete solution because it involves too many steps.

Comment: In that case, it's probably not related to the 4k-per-line limit in the line discipline, but is on the browser's end. In that case, there probably isn't that much you can do about it. If you're using a pastebin, you could use `wgetpaste` or similar, or might be able to improvise a command-line solution using `curl`, if you wanted to be really clever.

Comment: I don't think it's on the browser end, because I can't paste into other apps outside the terminal. Also, as I mentioned, I can copy-paste larger chunks of text into the browser as long as they were input into the clipboard in a different way, such as by sending the scrollback to a file, then opening it in an application outside the terminal and hitting `C-a C-c` to copy all.

Comment: If that's the case, then it's maybe somehow xsel's fault? `xsel -i` has to hang around waiting for something to paste, since the selection is an IPC mechanism and not a dedicated buffer; maybe something is interfering with that process. I've used this method before, though, and never had any problem.

Comment: Accepting since this is part of the best solution I know of now (send to file per this answer, open in Text Editor, C-a C-c, then paste). Would be great to resolve the underlying `xsel` issue though to get a simpler solution.